# Flutter drawer bottom image

Tags: flutter, drawer

[image: mydrawer]

Hi, I am pretty new to flutter/stack overflow and I am trying to create a navigation drawer divided into 3 parts: Profile Image, List tile and a bottom image that would cover the rest of the drawer as shown by the 3 rectangles in the image.

My problem is with the bottom image. I understand that I could add an image asset in the list view but it does not automatically fill the rest of the drawer. My idea was to add a child after the list view but I get an error: "the argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified"

Can anyone explain why this logic is not working and how could I make it work? Thank you!

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            // ***PROFILE IMAGE
            Container(
              height: 250,
              child: DrawerHeader(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Material(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/user.png',width: 200,height: 200,),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // ***LIST TILE
            CustomListTile(Icons.person, 'Profile',()=>{}),
            CustomListTile(Icons.add_location, 'Condominium',()=>{}),
            CustomListTile(Icons.map, 'Plan',()=>{}),
            CustomListTile(Icons.color_lens, 'Design',()=>{}),
          ],
        ),
        child: // ** I WOULD LIKE TO ADD PICTURE HERE
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the `Container` widget is a single child widget that only has one child. If you want to implement as your expectation, you need to use a `Column` is a child of the `Container`. The column will have the children with one is the List and one is the bottom image.

The image will use all the space of the bottom so you can wrap in an `Expanded` widget.

Here is an example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(children: [
          ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            // ***PROFILE IMAGE
            Container(
              height: 250,
              child: DrawerHeader(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Material(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/user.png',width: 200,height: 200,),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // ***LIST TILE
            CustomListTile(Icons.person, 'Profile',()=>{}),
            CustomListTile(Icons.add_location, 'Condominium',()=>{}),
            CustomListTile(Icons.map, 'Plan',()=>{}),
            CustomListTile(Icons.color_lens, 'Design',()=>{}),
          ],
        ),
          Expanded(
            child: // Your image here
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer ! I had an error : vertical viewport was given unbounded height : after a quick research I found out that I just needed to wrap the listview with an expanded widget